# Forward Internet access for a SBC that is connected with my PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet

**Update**

IP adresses after enabling the sharing function

```
Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::4ece:1a02:7677:2d01%19
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.183.200
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter WLAN:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: fritz.box
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : 2003:d0:ff0a:3d00:7330:2768:5147:c7c5
   Temporäre IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . : 2003:d0:ff0a:3d00:147d:71c4:7c7:2770
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::fa99:6d2f:fa1:3359%13
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.93
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::3681:c4ff:feb3:389f%13
                                       192.168.178.1
```

---

I connected a Linux SBC through Ethernet with my PC and both devices can ping the other device. My PC is connected to the Internet through WiFi. I want to forward this Internet access to the SBC.

I´ve read that I have to go `Network connections` on Windows, select the interface with internet access, switch the tab into `Sharing`, and enable the first point, and select the network interface where the internet should forwarded to.

[image]

But the ping on the SBC doesn´t work

```
root@imx6qpdlsolox:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.147.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.147.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.147.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Do I have to configure something else? In the last issue, the Windows Firewall was the problem. Might this be the case here too?

Comment: After enabling the connection sharing feature, what IP addresses does the Windows network interface now have? It was supposed to automatically change them when the feature was enabled.

Comment: Please check my update.

Comment: Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) makes your Windows box act as a NAT gateway and DHCP server on the private side. I would expect to see an RFC 1918 private IPv4 address on the private network interface (the Ethernet NIC itself, or maybe a virtual bridge device that the Ethernet NIC is a member of). I'd also expect the SBC to get assigned a private IP address on the same private subnet. I don't see either happening. This makes me wonder if ICS didn't successfully start up on your Windows box, or if maybe the SBC didn't try DHCP again yet. Try rebooting the SBC.

Comment: @Spiff I guess because I set the IP address of the device to a static one. I undo the change and enable DHCP, but the device still receives a `169...` address.

Comment: Guess I found the issue. For some reason, I have to reset the sharing functionality, confirm everything, enable it again, and then reboot the SBC. After that the IP address is fine and ping works. I have to repeat the process after each reboot of the Windows host. I also confirmed with another Windows PC that there is no Internet available on the shared Ethernet interface before I re-enable the sharing.